# Getting "Internal connection fatal error" while scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, scaffolding

I am creating my webApi project in .net 8. While scaffolding, I am getting internal server error.I am using My Sql database. I am using the below syntax and I am experimenting in Mac OS.

**dotnet ef dbcontext Scaffold "Server= <server_name>,<port_name>;Database=<DB_Name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model**

After running the above command, I am getting the following error.
[Output Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJhaJ.png)

What could be the solution I can use to solve this. I am frustrated since I have been dealing with this issue since past couple of days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there exists this line <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization> in your project file?

Comment: No. In AppSettings.json file?

Comment: The connection string you provided in your command is for Microsoft SQL Server (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`), not MySQL.

Comment: Alright. My problem has been resolved. Thanks a lot. 
*** FYI. ***
`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;port=----;user=---;password=---;database=dotnet" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o Model `

I used this command and it worked